# Undelete or recreate 'irc' bash command

Tags: bash, unix, osx-lion, irc, bin

(I'm running OS X 10.7 on a mid-2009 MBP.)

I was trying to uninstall ircII and I wound up deleting some irc commands in my /bin folder ("irc", "ircflush", "ircserv", etc).

I think that these might have been there before I installed ircII. If so, how do I get these back? Do I have to find the proper script and compile it or something?

Also (just out of curiosity) if someone deleted some really central bash command out of /bin, what would they do?

Comment: Try irssi - miles better than ircII :-)

Comment: pull them out of your time machine backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command "irc" exist by default in OS X, but the others don't.
And the "irc" executable isn't in "/bin".